# Is there a way to make an electron executable run without other files?

Tags: electron, exe

I'm wondering if it's possible to make an electron file run off of 'just the .exe'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UomJP.png

What I mean is, not have to use all the other .dlls and other files included in the export, so I would be able to send off the file or upload it for public usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using a NPM module like: `electron-builder` or `electron-winstaller` **instead** of `electron-packager`.

I'd recommend `electron-builder` as it's more customizable.

- Read about it here: https://www.electron.build/#installation

`electron-winstaller` on the otherhand is great if you just want a quick and easy `.exe`.

- Read about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-winstaller